# returning many values corresponding to one given value

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have this table in mysql database

```
number     | name         | friend
-------------------------------
1          |John          | Kloey
2          |John          | Tara
3          |Marco         | Tia
4          |John          | Clara
```

I need to get all the names in the friend column that corresponds to john in name column in an array or a string or anything that i can then receive in android? 
How can i do this?

Here's my php code but it just returns the 1st name which is kloey only

```
$username = $_POST["username"];
$recordofusername = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE name='$username'");
$value1 = mysql_fetch_array($recordofusername);
$user_friendname = $value1['friend'];
$response["userfriends"] = $user_friendname;

 echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Looking at your previous questions you **really** have to familiarize yourself with the concept of [upvoting and accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answers. If don't do that people will stop help you because you don't appreciate their time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

1. Please don't use deprecated `mysql_*` extension.
2. Don't interpolate query strings leaving your code vulnerable to sql injections. Learn and use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) with either [`mysqli_*`](http://www.php.net/mysqli) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/pdo)
3. When you get the resultset which contains more then one row you should iterate over the resultset to fetch all the rows, which you didn't in your code. And that's why with your code you always get the only one name from the first row in the resultset.
4. Don't use `SELECT *`. Instead explicitly tell what columns you need to select. In your case you just need `friend` column.

That being said to give you an idea how your code might look like using `mysqli`

```sql
$name = $_POST['username'];
$friends = array();
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'dbname');
if (!$db) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . $db->connect_error); //TODO: better error handling
}
$sql = "SELECT friend FROM friends WHERE name = ?";
if ($stmt = $db->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $name);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($friend);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) { // you have to iterate over the resultset
        $friends[] = $friend;
    }
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    die('Prepare failed: ' . $db->error); //TODO: better error handling
}
$db->close();

$response['userfriends'] = $friends;
echo json_encode($response);
```

Sample output:

```
{"userfriends":["Kloey","Tara","Clara"]}
```